# SQL*Net message from client on Idle event but active session

Tags: java, sql, oracle, cpu

In our application, facing high CPU usage issue due to SQL*Net message from client event which is showing idle event in V$SESSION but status is active. It looks very strange that session is active on idle event and causing high CPU usage. Interesting point is those sessions are not released from oracle database event after bringing down the client application and are only released after DB restart.

This behavior is very random in the application. The client application runs very well most of the times but sometimes it gets stuck and DB restart needed to bring back the application to normal state.

Any pointers which can help in finding root cause of this issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting session timeout parameter on client side so that idle session timeout after certain interval say 10 mins. You have that setting in sqlnet.ora

Comment: You can also - more effectively - set idle timeouts and other resource constraints in the database user profile.

Comment: Sounds like you are spinning on a lock / latch.  IE: one session has a latch, another session needs it, so it spins, tries again, and eventually sleeps and tries again.  I'd look at locks.  See https://www.orafaq.com/node/854 and https://geraldonit.com/oracle/database/oracle-database-locktypes/ -- I've seen this happen before.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's very useful and the issue looks around this only. But what would be solution to avoid this spinning lock as it's very random? Is there any configuration/settings which can help in this?

Comment: We are trying to define user resource limit in database but not sure if that can release the lock after defined timeout as those sessions does not get kill manually and only DB restart helps.

Comment: If your issue is being caused by a latch or lock, but it is randomly occurring, it could likely be the logic in a program that isn't working correctly in only certain situations, or perhaps only happens when some user might have multiple tabs open, etc.  Identifying the locks will hopefully help you find what session, and then what SQL statement, etc. is causing the issue.  So,  having the DBA kill the sessions identified as holding the locks is not helping to fix the immediate problem?